# Why is my for loop only displaying the last result?

Tags: c#

I want my `label2.Text` to display each concecutive result of the multiplication table, but only the last result gets displayed. 
I made that each checkbox equals only one math table. checkbox1 = multiplication table 1, checkbox2 = multiplication table 2 and so on...
Why is only the last result being displayed in my `label2.Text` property in my Windows Form?
P.S. I am working through an introduction course of C#.

```
int multiplyWith;
int multiplyNumber;
for (multiplyNumber = 1; multiplyNumber <= 12; multiplyNumber++)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        multiplyWith = 1;
        int sum = multiplyNumber * multiplyWith;
        label2.Visible = true;
        label2.Text = sum + "\n";

    }
    else if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
    {
        multiplyWith = 2;
        int sum = multiplyNumber * multiplyWith;
        label2.Visible = true;
        label2.Text = sum + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This has a lot of duplicates. The root cause is that C# does not get the control back from your method until after the loop is over.

Comment: you are replacing the result on every iteration

Comment: I know it is bad repetitive code, but does the variable holding the sum not get replaced with a new value and then be displayed with the for loop. I have tried placing the for loop inside of the if statement, but the result remains the same.

Comment: what do you mean I am replacing the value. I understand that the value needs to be replaced to be able to display the new value, but why does the new value not get displayed, but only replaced causing it to only display the last value?

Comment: @ChristoffelJoubert What is the value you want to be displayed in the `label2.Text` property? Please edit your question to include an example of your checkbox states and the result you want to have in `label2.Text`.

Comment: Some style advice: Don't say `if (checkBox2.Checked == true) ...` -- that is a very "new programmer" way to write that.  Basically you're saying "if it is true that the box is checked, then..." which you would probably not say in English; it sounds wordy.  You'd say "if the box is checked, then..."  So do that.  `if (checkBox2.Checked) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not concatenating the result but only setting the current value.

This would work but is not the most clean/efficient way to do it:

```
label2.Text += sum + "\n";
```

Try using a `StringBuilder` to generate the result first and at the end assign the text box the `StringBuilder` value.

```
StringBuilder sum = new StringBuilder();
int multiplyWith = checkBox1.Checked ? 1 : 2;

for (int multiplyNumber = 1; multiplyNumber <= 12; multiplyNumber++)
{
    sum.AppendLine(multiplyNumber * multiplyWith);
}    

label2.Visible = true;
label2.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: Snippets are for javascript/html/css only, please don't use them for c# code

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you could change it to something like:

```
int multiplyWith;
int multiplyNumber;
var results = string.Empty;
for (multiplyNumber = 1; multiplyNumber <= 12; multiplyNumber++)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        multiplyWith = 1;
        int sum = multiplyNumber * multiplyWith;
        label2.Visible = true;
        results += sum + "\n"
    }
    else if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
    {
        multiplyWith = 2;
        int sum = multiplyNumber * multiplyWith;
        label2.Visible = true;
        results += sum + "\n"
    } 
}
```

Then **after your loop exits**:

```
label2.Text = results;
```

Comment: Thank you. I did create a variable with an empty value, which i believe is same as string.Empty. It was the += before the sum that i missed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could just edit this line from

```
label2.Text = sum + "\n";
```

to

```
label2.Text += sum + "\n";
```

Comment: thank you. that is exactly what i was looking for. I knew it was something small because the logic made sense to me.